# Why does SVG viewed in Chrome 51 not position correctly with added gap after text?

Tags: html, svg, browser

I made a simple Scalable Vector Graphic image (using the Inkscape tool v0.91). The editor was displaying it all properly however when I opened the file in Google Chrome 51 it wasn't displayed like it should, with the **positioning wrong** (an added gap after some text). I created a simpler example version which is shown here where an embedded image on the left is removed and a line is added to the original where the horizontal text on the left should end.
**The original image (viewed in the editor):**
[image: Image described on above line, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lay4B.png]
**The image viewed in the Google Chrome 51 browser:**
[image: Image described on above line, https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyVPZ.png]
I don't understand why this would be happening as the browser should be drawing the text in the image at the same font size and position as the image describes, scaling them if the zoom is changed. A look at the element viewer in the developer tools **confirms that the text did not have a smaller font size attribute** and both viewers were at **the same zoom level**. The image shown in the editor is saved to the file and not modified before being used by the browser so it is definitely a browser problem. Even if no one can find the reason for this problem, I would still like a solution.

Here is an example image to reproduce the issue and test with (I forgot this earlier and was recommended to). SVG image host servers seemed rare so I added it as a code snippet however it can be copied back into a file with the `.svg` extension to be viewed normally in a browser.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="135.972"
   height="40"
   viewBox="0 0 135.97202 39.999998"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="test.svg"
   inkscape:export-filename="C:\blah\logo.png"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="90"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="90">
  <defs
     id="defs4">
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker4688"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Send">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.2,0,0,-0.2,-1.2,0)"
         style="fill:#a5a5a5;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 Z"
         id="path4690"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <linearGradient
       osb:paint="gradient"
       id="linearGradient9980">
      <stop
         id="stop9982"
         offset="0"
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop
         id="stop9984"
         offset="1"
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0;" />
    </linearGradient>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Send"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="marker4688-8"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="path4690-0"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 Z"
         style="fill:#a5a5a5;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(-0.2,0,0,-0.2,-1.2,0)" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible;"
       id="marker4688-5"
       refX="0.0"
       refY="0.0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Send">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.2) rotate(180) translate(6,0)"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1;fill:#a5a5a5;fill-opacity:1"
         d="M 0.0,0.0 L 5.0,-5.0 L -12.5,0.0 L 5.0,5.0 L 0.0,0.0 z "
         id="path4690-1" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="2"
     inkscape:cx="41.427915"
     inkscape:cy="11.725916"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2"
     showgrid="false"
     units="px"
     inkscape:window-width="961"
     inkscape:window-height="601"
     inkscape:window-x="336"
     inkscape:window-y="51"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="false"
     showborder="true"
     borderlayer="false" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <text
     xml:space="preserve"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:13.75000191px;line-height:94.99999881%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:start;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#00007c;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     x="23.658821"
     y="16.700916"
     id="text4409"
     sodipodi:linespacing="94.999999%"><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="23.658821"
       y="16.700916"
       id="tspan4413"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16.25000381px;line-height:94.99999881%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#00007c;fill-opacity:1"><tspan
         rotate="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
         id="tspan4465"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16.25000381px;line-height:94.99999881%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif Bold Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#00007c;fill-opacity:1">Text that</tspan></tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="23.658821"
       y="32.13842"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16.25000381px;line-height:94.99999881%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#00007c;fill-opacity:1"
       dx="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10"
       dy="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
       id="tspan4473"><tspan
         id="tspan4475"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16.25000381px;line-height:94.99999881%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#00007c;fill-opacity:1">gets moved</tspan></tspan></text>
  <text
     xml:space="preserve"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:13.75000191px;line-height:70.99999785%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:start;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     x="133.1541"
     y="7.5629053"
     id="text4409-4"
     sodipodi:linespacing="70.999998%"
     transform="scale(0.99999351,1.0000065)"><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="7.5629053"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:0%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       id="tspan4473-1">t</tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="11.79909"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:85.00000238%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       id="tspan4231">e</tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="16.114841"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:64.99999762%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       id="tspan4233">s</tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="21.423279"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:89.99999762%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       id="tspan4235">t</tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="26.799091"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:85.00000238%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       id="tspan4237">i</tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="31.114843"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:64.99999762%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       id="tspan4239">n</tspan><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       x="133.1541"
       y="35.476368"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.25000095px;line-height:70.99999785%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Bold';text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#0050a0;fill-opacity:1"
       rotate="0 0"
       dy="0 0"
       dx="0 10.000066"
       id="tspan4241">g</tspan></text>
  <path
     style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 129.69402,1.1636744e-6 0,39.9999998363256"
     id="path4340"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cc" />
</svg>
```

User [*@rhashimoto*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462337/rhashimoto)'s [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427262/3787376) explains how it is a font problem, not a browser or Inkscape problem. The text font name was set to `sans-serif` which specifies a group of fonts instead of a specific font which allowed Inkscape to chose a different font to Google Chrome when displaying, causing the text dimensions to be different. Both setting the font name to "Arial" and converting the text to a path solved the problem.

Comment: Please provide an image that reproduces the issue. (Like change the personal text in your example and link it here as an svg)

Comment: Done! Read the edited post @TamasHegedus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SVG text elements contain a `font-family` attribute with value `sans-serif`. This value does not specify a particular font, only that the font selected should not contain serifs. Inkscape and Chrome are using different sans-serif fonts, and these fonts produce text of different widths.

It appears that [Inkscape tries to use DejaVu Sans](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=20056) if present as its sans-serif font. On Chrome, go to chrome://settings/fonts to see the sans-serif font - on my machine it is Helvetica.

Since the text layout is important to you, you should [assign a specific font](http://www.ehow.com/how_7275960_change-font-inkscape.html) to your text objects. For example, you could change your text elements in Inkscape to explicitly have a `font-family` of 'DejaVu Sans' (you can also try it in Chrome Developer Tools). Then the resulting SVG should use the same font in Chrome *as long as Chrome supports that font on your target platforms*.

That last caveat means that you should not expect any arbitrary esoteric font to reproduce properly across all browsers and machines. You may want to read the "Fonts In SVG" section of http://nimbupani.com/about-fonts-in-svg.html.

You also have the option of [converting the text to a path](https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/52430). Note, however, that this loses the textual content so it can't be copied to the clipboard, read by a screen reader, etc.

Comment: Good useful answer - you get the bounty reward! I forgot about the font dimensions and suspected incorrect text positions caused by Google Chrome or Inkscape. My Chrome uses Arial instead of what Inkscape uses (perhaps DejaVu Sans as you suggest). Converting the text font to Arial produces the same gap as Chrome displays on the original in Inkscape and converting the text to path preserves the text appearance. I will use the convert to path method to not rely on specific fonts.

Comment: OMG I was going nuts about this. Thx for this ---> "This value does not specify a particular font"